# property of complex gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

> Show that 
>   $$|(n+ib)!|= \left( \frac{\pi b}{\sinh(\pi b)}\right)^{{1}/{2}}\prod_{s=1}^{n}{(s^2+b^2)^{{1}/{2}}}$$

I have the following relations

$$\frac{\sinh(b \pi)}{b\pi} = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[1+\frac{b^2}{(n+1)^2}\right] $$

and
$$ |\Gamma(1+ib)|^{-2} = \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[1+\frac{b^2}{(n+1)^2}\right]  $$

My attempt:
$$|(n+ib)!|= |\Gamma(n+ib+1)|$$  then
$$  |\Gamma(n+ib+1)|^2 = \Gamma(n+ib+1)\Gamma(n-ib+1)$$ then
$$ \Gamma(n+ib+1)\Gamma(n-ib+1) = \left( \frac{\pi b}{\sinh(\pi b)} \right)\prod_{s=1}^{n}{(s^2+b^2)}$$

I do not know how to eliminate n variable in gamma function so that I can proceed using the relations listed above.  Any ideas?